# Cloud Management Software

Tags: virtual-machine, cloud-computing, openstack

We currently manage about 60 virtual machines on 6 physical servers with [virt-manager](http://virt-manager.org/).

We consider to use a more professional cloud computing software.

We have never worked with OpenStack, CloudStack, oVirt, ....

Any recommendations?

**Update**

What we don't like about `virt-manager`:

- AFAIK it does no automatic fail over if one of the physical servers fail.

**Update2**

- We use Ubuntu and OpenSuSE as guest and host operating sytems

Comment: Are you looking for a free solution?  If not, look at Azure.

Comment: @rrirower it could be a commercial solution, too. But we don't have any windows os running in our company. I guess our admin does not want to use Azure (a microsoft solution) just for that.

Comment: I've not tried this *personally* but [conga/luci/ricci](http://magazine.redhat.com/2007/03/19/teaching-your-cluster-and-storage-systems-to-dance-an-introduction-to-conga/) looks like a start. What do you run your hosts on and what are your guests?